# Probability doubt - checking whether my thinking is right (answer doesn't match the book)

Tags: probability

A box contains three $ red (R)$ and two $blue (B)$ flies. Two flies are removed with replacement. Let $A$ be the event that both the flies are of the same color and $B$ be the event that at least one of the flies is red.

Find

**i)** $P (B)$: My thinking - you remove a combination of BB - probability $ \frac{2}{20}$

And then just subtract it from $1$, giving you an answer of $\frac{18}{20}$. The book says that the answer is $0.6$. Even intuitively this seems like a pretty low probability to me.

**ii)** $P( A \cup B)$= this will obviously go wrong since the previous answer went wrong. But still, just writing my thinking: I used the standard union formula, getting a probability of $1$ and that makes sense to me. The book's answer is $0.7$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Side not.  If $B$ is an event you might not want to use $B$ to mean "blue" as well.... not a show stopper but...

Comment: @d.k.o The probability that the first fly is blue is $2/5.$  Since this is sampling with replacement, the probability that the second fly is blue is also $2/5$, so the probability that both flies are blue is $4/25$.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: With replacement.... So the probability that both are blue is $(\frac 25)^2 = \frac 4{25}$ so the prob a least one redii is $\frac {21}{25}$.  The book is wrong (which is ath prob the *first* is red is $\frac 35$ the probability that the first is red or the first isn't but the second is must be higher).

Comment: A union B means either a) both are blue or both red or b) at least one red.  If there isn't at least one red they are both blue so one or the other has to happen.  So prob is 1.  So the book has an error or you are not stating the question right.

Comment: @fleablood I have copied the question straight from the textbook so that there is no error/omission on my part.

Comment: The textbook has an error.  It happens.  So far as I can tell you got the correct answer for doing it with*out* replacement (I actually made the same error until I saw salspatz comment).  But the book seems to be wrong.